# C++: cast function<void(shared_ptr<Animal>)> to function<void(shared_ptr<Dog>)>

Tags: c++, function, casting, callback

I do not know C++ too well, can not find anything on this callback being a mixture of `function`, `shared_ptr` and a cast to a narrower type. Is this possible in C++ and how to do this?

EDIT: Yeah solution is in the comment of Nathan. There was also a answer which clarified the interesting details, but it disappeared.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample showing how you are currently trying to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't need the cast.  The classes should be polymorphic and accessed from a common interface.

Comment: You are right,there must have been a problem in another place which caused cryptic compiler errors... thanks.